# Frame does not open correctly at calculator program in JAVA although it compiled correctly

Tags: java

This my code :

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
class CalcFrame extends JFrame {
    private JButton btnClear;
    private JButton btnEquals;
    private JLabel lblDisplay;
    private JButton[] btnOps = new JButton[4];
public CalcFrame(){
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setBounds(122,444 ,322,123);
    }
}
```

following image shows, the result that i have :

[frame image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRDF8.jpg)

Comment: Use [`setSize(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setSize-int-int-). Or better yet, don't size the frame directly at all. Instead, fill it with components, then use [`pack()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack--) to size the frame based on what's inside of it.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but using setSize does not effect on the result. there is another issue I have, close button doesn't work correctly and i don't know why?

Comment: The code above doesn't show the creation of the frame, nor setting it visible.  We appreciate minimizing the code that you post to the bare minimum, but in this case you've perhaps removed too much.  I've never seen a problem with `setSize()` not working...

Comment: The code in the image that you've linked to creates a `JFrame`. Have you tried creating a `CalcFrame` instead?

Comment: @jchamp - Good catch!  I didn't think to read the code in the image, but I was guessing that is what we'd see!

Answer (score 1):

As I suspected, and @jchamp pointed out in the comments, your `main` code reads:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame mx = new JFrame();
    mx.setVisible();
}
```

The code in the `CalcFrame` constructor is not executed, so any `setBounds()` or `setSize()` call is not executed and will therefore have no effect.  This also explains the close button not terminating the application, because the `setDefaultCloseOperation` is also never called.

Instead, create and show your `CalcFrame`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CalcFrame mx = new CalcFrame();
    mx.setVisible();
}
```